# Function equals as default value for a function in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following method:

```
def foo[B](fn: (B,B) => Boolean): Unit = {
  // do something       
}
```

Is there a way to provide a default value of `equals` to the parameter `fn`?

I have tried

`def foo[B](fn: (B,B) => Boolean = ==): Unit = ...`

but it fails. (I have also tried `==[B]`, `equals[B]`, `B.equals`, etc. but none work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that:

```
def foo[B](fn: (B,B) => Boolean = (a:B, b:B) => a == b)
```

works.

I have also re-learnt that a method and a function are not the same thing.

Comment: `_ == _` should also do the trick if you want to save few chars.

Comment: @maasg I thought so too, but the compiler rejects it.

Comment: I tried. You're right. The underscore syntax is not allowed in that case.